# avoid automatic jump to bottom on page with iframe video

Tags: iframe, video-embedding

I have a video showing on a page like this

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{skin url="video/hande.mp4"}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

but when loading the page on tablet / mobile the page automatically jumps to the bottom where the video is. I tried adding something like this

```
<iframe style="display: none;" onload="this.style.display='block';" href="..."></iframe>
```

following from this question [iframe on the page bottom: avoid automatic scroll of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596668/iframe-on-the-page-bottom-avoid-automatic-scroll-of-the-page) but the suggestions on there don't work for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The OP has found an acceptable solution by utilizing `scrollTo`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[ window.onload = function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }// ]]>
</script>
```

> which seems to work, there's a bit of a delay though so its not great but so far its the only thing that seems to have worked.

So to add to OP's solution, try:

```
<script>
    // <![CDATA[ document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, false )// ]]>
</script>
```

Using `window.onload` means your function will be called after everything else has loaded; DOM, images, script, etc.

Using `DOMContentLoaded` means your function will be called after the DOM has loaded (which means after any iframes have loaded, which is usually the slowest part of the DOM content). What it doesn't wait for is script, so make sure you place the YouTube script before this line. There are exceptions of course see [**ARTICLE**](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded#domcontentloaded)

**UPDATE**

It seems that the `focus` event could be the culprit so what you can do is offer the browser to focus on something else.

- Create a temporary transparent input while page is loading.
- When the page is fully loaded, use a callback to remove the input.

Forgot to actually update the snippet...so it's added now.

Try this snippet below.  View in 'Full Page'. You have to scroll down to the bottom and to your right, because it ain't gonna scroll without help.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

window.load = function() {
  var fpt = document.querySelector('.focalPoint');
  fpt.parentNode.removeChild(fpt);
}

function init() {
  var fpt = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(fpt);
  fpt.classList.add('focalPoint');
  if (fpt != document.activeElement) {
    fpt.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50vw;
  /* Arbitrary */
}
.vidWrap {
  position: relative;
  /* Anchor the iframe's parent */
  padding-bottom: 56%;
  /* This is for AR 16:9 (ie. wide screen) videos */
  padding-top: 20px;
  /* Offset to padding-bottom */
  height: 0;
  /* Makes a tight 'seal' */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* Ensures that edges aren't breached */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* As above */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* For iOS7 ... not so sure about iOS8 or iOS9 */
  bottom: -50vw;
  /* Arbitrary. */
  left: 50vw;
  /* Arbitrary */
}
.vid {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* See above */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* As above */
  height: 100%;
  /* stretched to the edge of parent */
  width: 100%;
  /* As above */
  position: absolute;
  /* Allows control within the parent */
  /* These coords will stretch the iframe seemlessly to parent's edges */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.focalPoint {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <div class="vidWrap">
    <iframe id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/023642.mp4" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried with this but still get the automatic jump on mobile/tablet

Comment: @user2681654 Did you add `scrolling='no'` to the iframe?

Comment: Yes like so                                                                                        <section class="box"><div class="vidWrap">
    <iframe id="vid1" class="vid" src="{{skin url="video/handmade.mp4"}}" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe></div>

Comment: You're not actually using `<pre>` and `<code>` , right?  I'm assuming your'e using it just for posting on this site. If the latter is correct, just wrap your code with ` (the key is located on the left and top of keyboard right under the `Esc` key.

Comment: Is `{{ }}` a template?

Comment: No the `pre code` is only here, thanks! `{{ }}` is used in Magento, but even if I link the exact same as your example above I still get the jump

Comment: Ive added this to the page `<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
window.onload = function(){
 window.scrollTo(0,0);
}// ]]></script>` which seems to work, there's a bit of a delay though so its not great but so far its the only thing that seems to have worked

Comment: Glad you got it. See my updated post  to coincide with your solution.