# iframe invokes scroll, no idea why

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, focus

Whenever I integrate one of my virtual tour applications through an iframe on a webpage, the page load invokes a scroll to the iframe. It only happens in Microsoft Edge and Safari, not on Chrome or Firefox.

I thought it would be caused by a `blabla.focus();` somewhere in my javascript, but I haven't got any. What could be the probable cause and how should I start looking for it?

Examples can be found at
[Villa Margaux Website](http://lefkada-villamargaux.com)
[YOUREKA Website](http://www.youreka.be)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoid automatic jump to bottom on page with iframe video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527748/avoid-automatic-jump-to-bottom-on-page-with-iframe-video)

Comment: The iframe is my own code, the website in which it is implemented not necessarily, so no, no duplicate.

Comment: The *behaviour* is what's likely duplicate, not the code per se. Check the link and see if the answers in that question resolve yours.

Comment: I can't use the suggested solutions there as I don't have control over the website itself, only over the iframe.