# When page loads it jumps down to the iframe - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

We are trying to add an iframe from ADP to our careers page here: https://longo.inventivewd.com/careers/. This is a WordPress site that uses Astra theme and Elementor.

When the page fully loads it automatically jumps down to the iframe. I don't know if this is due to some of the code from the ADP page within the iframe or my settings.

ADP link: https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid=85e1d0f8-8d9d-4e45-ae2f-7071a17656c8&ccId=19000101_000001&lang=en_US

My iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid=85e1d0f8-8d9d-4e45-ae2f-7071a17656c8&ccId=19000101_000001&lang=en_US" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="ADP" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="1200px" width="100%"  ></iframe>
```

I have tried to apply various answers from older posts like this one: [iframe on the page bottom: avoid automatic scroll of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596668/iframe-on-the-page-bottom-avoid-automatic-scroll-of-the-page) but nothing seems to work.

Yes, I have tried setting scrolling to no but this just removes the scroll bar that I need for mobile devices.

I have tried adding this:

```
style="display: none;" onload="this.style.display='block';"
```

and this:

```
style="position: absolute; top: -9999em; visibility: hidden;" onload="this.style.position='static'; this.style.visibility='visible';"
```

Nothing from the above mentioned post (and others) works.

Does anyone have a solution to this or is it something that ADP would have to change on their end?

Comment: ADP will have to remove their autofocus